# ModBus to Click PLC

Tags: modbus, plc

Looking for help with understanding how to change value in address DS1 (400001).  First the click appears to use a 6 digit Modbus so not sure how to deal with the in 2 bytes.  I think I read 40001 is the same but do not see how.  I am able to receive data and understand the data when the Click PLC is the master.  I would like my PC to be the master and change the address.

Here is the data I am sending to the PLC.  I am expecting this data to be sent to PLC slave 02 and change the data in DS1 (400001) to the value of zero.

```
    frame(0) = 2 'Slave Address =2 
    frame(1) = 6 'Mode =6  
    frame(2) = CByte(40001 / 256) '
    frame(3) = CByte(40001 Mod 256) '
    frame(4) = 0 '
    frame(5) = 0 '
    Dim crc As Byte() = CRC(frame) ' Call CRC Calculate.
    frame(6) = crc(0) '=59 Error Check Lo
    frame(7) = crc(1) '=189 Error Check Hi

    SerialPort1.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length)
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox next to it to Accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that Application Layer addressing in Modbus is different than the bytes on the wire.  The leading digit in an application layer address (e.g. 4xxxx for Holding Register) is implied in the function code (e.g. Read Holding Register)

So on the wire, you drop the leading 4, and left with an offset of 1-65536 (yes, Application Layer offsets are 1-based).  But on the WIRE, they are 0-based, so you then subtact 1 from the offset to get the value 0-65535.

So, sometimes you see Application Modbus HRs like 4001, 40001, or 400001, all referencing the first HR in the device.  5 digit is most common.  I do see 4 digit for old RTU devices.  I do see a 6 digit every once in a while where the remote device has a ton of memory (or not, like Click).

Realize that a lot of devices are implemented by people who only understand the low level protocol, so when they say something is at address 40001, it may actually be at offset 0x0001, or 0x0000 (the correct offset on the wire).  I even saw one implementation that implemented the address 40001 as literally 0x9C41 on the wire (maybe 0x9C40).  Yes, 6 digit Application Layer Holding Register 440001.

Comment: Great help thank you.  I have it working. dropping the leading 4 is what was needed.